# Change row numbers when row is deleted with button click Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a GUI that adds 2 entry boxes when a button is clicked.

- First entry box is showing number of rows.
- The second entry boxis showing some value.

Next to the entry boxes I have made a button ("-"). When you click that button it destroys the entries and the "-" button.

I want to change rows number so it fits the order, when button is clicked. If I add 6 rows and I delete 4th row I have row numbers: 1,2,3,5,6. I want to have 1,2,3,4,5.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" MY GUI")                         
myApp.geometry("700x599")

num_rows = 1

class Adding(object):
    def Finish(self):

        global num_rows

        num_rows += 1
        n=num_rows-1

        def delete():
            bdelete.destroy()
            newE0.destroy()
            newE1.destroy()

        bdelete=Button(myApp,text="-",command=delete)    
        newE0=Entry(myApp,width=2)
        newE1=Entry(myApp,width=10)

        bdelete.grid(column=0,row=num_rows,padx=3)    
        newE0.grid(column=1,row=num_rows,padx=3)
        newE1.grid(column=2,row=num_rows,padx=3)

        newE0.insert(0,n)
        newE1.insert(0,5)

    def __init__(self):

        button4=Button(myApp,text="Finish",width="17", command=self.Finish)
        button4.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="w",pady=3 )

Adding=Adding()
myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want.

You have to remember the entries in some way. I used a class level list.
I also changed the structure of your code, so it doesn't use global variables.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Adding(Tk):
    entry_list = []
    num_rows = 1

    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(" MY GUI")
        self.geometry("700x599")

        button4 = Button(self, text="Finish", width="17", command=self.finish)
        button4.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w", pady=3)

    def finish(self):
        self.num_rows += 1

        newE0 = Entry(self, width=2)
        newE1 = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry_list.append(newE0)

        def delete():
            bdelete.destroy()
            newE0.destroy()
            newE1.destroy()
            self.entry_list.remove(newE0)
            self.update_values()

        bdelete = Button(self, text="-", command=delete)

        bdelete.grid(column=0, row=self.num_rows, padx=3)
        newE0.grid(column=1, row=self.num_rows, padx=3)
        newE1.grid(column=2, row=self.num_rows, padx=3)

        n = len(self.entry_list)
        newE0.insert(0, n)
        newE1.insert(0, 5)

    def update_values(self):
        for i, entry in enumerate(self.entry_list):
            entry.delete(0, "end")
            entry.insert(0, i + 1)


myApp = Adding()
myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: And whats your advice for Adding,globals?

Comment: I changed my answer to show you roughly what I meant.